# Not able to delete a test case from Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, testcase

I have administrator privileges for Visual Studio Team Services. I access it through url:

https://[myaccoutname].visualstudio.com/[projectname]

I get below message when I tried to delete a test case:

"Failed to delete work item: 1200. Error Details: VS402838: The work item 1200 cannot be deleted. Test Case work items cannot be deleted."

Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `witadmin destroywi` command to **permanently remove work items** from the data store. However, a permanent delete means all information in the WIT data store is deleted and cannot be restored nor reactivated.

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:CollectionURL /id:id [/noprompt]
```

More details please refer the paragraph  *Permanently delete work items* from MSDN link: [Move, change, or delete work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items)

> ***Note:*** Required permissions- For Team Services and TFS 2015 Update 2 or
>   later versions, you must have *Permanently delete work items permission*
>   *set to **Allow**.*

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft said the following on 5/4/2016 (See [Deleted Test Plans, Test Suites and Test Cases still show up in queries](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2664163/deleted-test-plans-test-suites-and-test-cases-still-show-up-in-queries)):

> We dont support yet the deletion of test artifacts (test plan, test suites and test cases) from Work Item store, tough we allow deletion of them from test store. We have this item on our backlog to cleanup work item store as well and bring consistency. As of today, it is a known issue and we are working on it with very high priority. As it becomes available, we will notify users.